# subalgebra of a division algebra is a division algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that every subalgebra of a division algebra is a division 
algebra. 
This is true for finite dimensional case but for infinite case?

Answer (score 3):

$k[x]$ is a subalgebra of $k(x)$